# Make Rows into Extension Column on Queried Rows Only SQL

Tags: sql

Alright so I have this table...

```
CID    CAmountDescription    CAmount
A-19        Payment           500.00
A-19        Loan               50.00
A-20        Payment           100.00  
A-20        Loan               20.00
```

I'd like to query against the database in such a way that the returned rows are like this...

```
CID    Payment   Loan
A-19    500.00   50.00       
A-20    100.00   20.00
```

I tried using some kind of JOIN clause, since it's the only way I know to add columns, but it returns more rows than desired. I'd appreciate it if anybody could help me on this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    CID,
    sum(if(CAmountDescription='Payment',CAmount,0)) as Payment,
    sum(if(CAmountDescription='Loan',CAmount,0)) as Loan
from the_table
group by CID
```

Comment: Hi @StanislavL Thank you for this. It works like a charm. I'll make this as the answer because it doesn't involve subqueries, thus, is faster :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct t1.CID, 
    (select t2.CAmount from your_table t2 where t2.CAmountDescription = 'Payment' and t2.CID = t1.CID) "Payment",
    (select t2.CAmount from your_table t2 where t2.CAmountDescription = 'Loan' and t2.CID = t1.CID) "Loan"
from your_table t1
```

Comment: Hi @sh_kamalh Thank you very much for your answer. With minor changes, your SQL statement works. I appreciate it so I'll vote your answer up, but I'll choose StanislavL's answer since it's much more efficient, at least the way I see it since it doesn't involve subqueries. Thank you.